# What's the meaning of the "Psp" in “PspCreatePicoProcess"

Tags: windows, visual-c++, msdn

prefix `Ps` is : **process support**

prefix `Rtl` is : **Run-time library**

But I don't know, the `Psp` it also appears in `PspAllocateProcess` and `PspInsertProcess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Windows Internals](https://books.google.com/books?id=WZdCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT140&lpg=PT140) that would be "*process support - private*":

> Each of these major executive components also uses a variation of the prefix to denote internal functions - either the first letter of the prefix followed by an *i* (for internal), or the full prefix followed by a *p* (for private). For example, *Ki* represents internal kernel functions, and *Psp* refers to internal process support functions.